# API call - Accessing JSON objects Rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, api, parsing

I am trying to call [API](https://api.gouv.fr/documentation/api_open_data_education_nationale) to query dataset records so user can find a school in my app.
Basically i'd like to be able find school name matching with their input.
At this stage i have only tried to implemanet API call and save school but i am kinda of stuck now and struggle to access data from Json.

api_schools.rb

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

class ApiSchools

  def call
    set_url
    set_school
    create_school
  end

  def set_url
    @url = URI("https://data.education.gouv.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=fr-en-annuaire-education")
  end

  def set_school
    http = Net::HTTP.new(@url.host, @url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(@url)
    response = http.request(request)
    @schools = JSON.parse(response.read_body)["records"]
    ap @schools
  end

  def create_school
    @schools.each do |school|
      ## set records
      id = school["id"]
      identifiant_de_l_etablissement = school["identifiant_de_l_etablissement"]
      name = school["nom_etablissement"]
      type = school["type_etablissement"]
      status = school["statut_public_prive"]
      nombre_d_eleves = school["nombre_d_eleves"]
      adresse_1 = school["adresse_1"]
      adresse_3 = school["adresse_3"]
      code_postal = school["code_postal"]
      city = school["nom_commune"]
      departement = school["libelle_departement"]
      address = school["voie"]
      email = school["mail"]
      phone = school["telephone"]

      ## Create school
      school =  School.new(id: id, identifiant_de_l_etablissement: identifiant_de_l_etablissement, nom_etablissement: name, type_etablissement: type, statut_public_prive: status, nombre_d_eleves: nombre_d_eleves, adresse_1: adresse_1, adresse_3: adresse_3, code_postal: code_postal, nom_commune: city, libelle_departement: departement, voie: address, mail: email, telephone: phone)
      ap school
      school.save
    end
  end

end
```

Json

```
"records":[
{
"datasetid":"fr-en-annuaire-education",
"recordid":"9a1e2add53ae2d5e885c0b478a33134cae58b7c4",
"fields":{
"code_nature":151,
"nom_etablissement":"Ecole primaire Ernest Pérochon",
"nombre_d_eleves":138,
"multi_uai":0,
"type_etablissement":"Ecole",
"code_commune":"79270",
"rpi_concentre":0,
"statut_public_prive":"Public",
"epsg_origine":"EPSG:2154",
"code_academie":"13",
"hebergement":0,
"ulis":0,
"date_ouverture":"1967-08-04",
"identifiant_de_l_etablissement":"0790399E",
"telephone":"0549055362",
"date_maj_ligne":"2022-05-17",
"nom_circonscription":"Circonscription d'inspection du 1er degré de Niort Saint Maixent",
"adresse_1":"Rue de la Gare",
"libelle_region":"Nouvelle-Aquitaine",
"ecole_elementaire":1,
"position":[
46.406925271843825,
-0.20278001351916794
],
"coordx_origine":454027.8,
"precision_localisation":"Numéro de rue",
"libelle_zone_animation_pedagogique":"SUD DEUX-SEVRES",
"longitude":-0.20278001351916794,
"etat":"OUVERT",
"code_departement":"079",
"ecole_maternelle":1,
"adresse_3":"79400 ST MAIXENT L ECOLE",
"restauration":1,
"coordy_origine":6594652.7,
"ministere_tutelle":"MINISTERE DE L'EDUCATION NATIONALE",
"code_zone_animation_pedagogique":"13792",
"code_type_contrat_prive":"99",
"type_contrat_prive":"SANS OBJET",
"libelle_departement":"Deux-Sèvres",
"latitude":46.406925271843825,
"pial":"0790978J",
"siren_siret":"21790270900062",
"code_postal":"79400",
"nom_commune":"Saint-Maixent-l'Ecole",
"libelle_academie":"Poitiers",
"libelle_nature":"ECOLE DE NIVEAU ELEMENTAIRE",
"code_region":"75",
"mail":"ce.0790399E@ac-poitiers.fr"
},
"geometry":{
"type":"Point",
"coordinates":[
-0.20278001351916794,
46.406925271843825
]
},
"record_timestamp":"2022-05-17T16:04:00Z"
},
```

```
irb(main):001:0> ApiSchools.new.call
    [0] {
               "datasetid" => "fr-en-annuaire-education",
                "recordid" => "7c3fb5e473a93b3858fe6e57deb8c38b5ee5c35a",
                  "fields" => {
                               "code_nature" => 151,
                         "nom_etablissement" => "Ecole élémentaire Albert PERRAUD",
                                 "multi_uai" => 0,
                        "type_etablissement" => "Ecole",
                              "code_commune" => "98818",
                             "rpi_concentre" => 0,
                       "statut_public_prive" => "Public",
                             "code_academie" => "40",
                               "hebergement" => 0,
                                      "ulis" => 0,
                            "date_ouverture" => "1994-03-01",
            "identifiant_de_l_etablissement" => "9830505G",
                                 "telephone" => "0687240624",
                            "date_maj_ligne" => "2022-05-17",
                       "nom_circonscription" => "Circonscription d'inspection du 1er degré de Nouméa - I.E.P. 1ère circonscription",
                                 "adresse_1" => "11  RUE DE TIGA MAGENTA",
                            "libelle_region" => "TOM et Collectivités territoriales",
                         "ecole_elementaire" => 1,
                                      "etat" => "OUVERT",
                          "code_departement" => "988",
                          "ecole_maternelle" => 0,
                                 "adresse_2" => "BP 14372",
                                 "adresse_3" => "98803 NOUMEA CEDEX",
                              "restauration" => 0,
                         "ministere_tutelle" => "MINISTERE DE L'EDUCATION NATIONALE",
                   "code_type_contrat_prive" => "99",
                        "type_contrat_prive" => "SANS OBJET",
                       "libelle_departement" => "Nouvelle Calédonie",
                               "siren_siret" => "20001250800327",
                               "code_postal" => "98803",
                               "nom_commune" => "Nouméa",
                          "libelle_academie" => "Nouvelle Calédonie",
                            "libelle_nature" => "ECOLE DE NIVEAU ELEMENTAIRE",
                               "code_region" => "00",
                                      "mail" => "direcole.perraud@province-sud.nc"
        },
        "record_timestamp" => "2022-05-17T16:04:00Z"
    },
 
]
#<School:0x00007fda2033a728> {
                                :id => nil,
    :identifiant_de_l_etablissement => nil,
                 :nom_etablissement => nil,
                :type_etablissement => nil,
               :statut_public_prive => nil,
                   :nombre_d_eleves => nil,
                         :adresse_1 => nil,
                         :adresse_3 => nil,
                       :code_postal => nil,
                       :nom_commune => nil,
               :libelle_departement => nil,
                              :voie => nil,
                              :mail => nil,
                         :telephone => nil,
                               :lab => nil,
                        :created_at => nil,
                        :updated_at => nil
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of how you failed to access data from that JSON object? I'm struggling to understand precisely where you are stuck and what you are trying to solve

Comment: @chriszo111 Sorry if i was not clear, i am newbie in Rails and API. At first i will like access fields keys so i can create a school. Then i would like my user to find school with their matching input.
I have edited my post and added result in the console.

Answer (score 1):

After parsing the result you received from the URL:

- `api_schools.rb` (line `23`)

```rb
@schools = JSON.parse(response.read_body)["records"]
```

you will end up with a nested hash that looks like this:

`[{datasetid:"..",...},{"datasetid":"...",...},...]`

In your `create_schools` method, when you iterate over `@schools`, outputting the current item to the console

- `api_schools.rb` (line `28`)

```rb
@schools.each do |school|
  puts school
  break
  ## set records
  ...
end
```

will show you the first item of the array, that looks like this:

```rb
{
   "datasetid""=>""fr-en-annuaire-education",
   "recordid""=>""1f459a0053d4c075a56d5d81a96d4a4acc0ba963",
   "fields""=>"{
      "code_nature"=>151,
      "nom_etablissement""=>""Ecole élémentaire Guillaumes",
      "nombre_d_eleves"=>27,
      "multi_uai"=>0,
      "type_etablissement""=>""Ecole",
      "code_commune""=>""06071",
      "rpi_concentre"=>0,
      "statut_public_prive""=>""Public",
      "epsg_origine""=>""EPSG:2154",
      "code_academie""=>""23",
      "hebergement"=>0,
      "ulis"=>0,
      "date_ouverture""=>""1965-07-05",
      "identifiant_de_l_etablissement""=>""0060285C",
      "telephone""=>""0493055087",
      "date_maj_ligne""=>""2022-05-29",
      "nom_circonscription""=>""Circonscription d'inspection du 1er degré de Carros 3 Vallées",
      "adresse_1""=>""Place de Provence",
      "libelle_region""=>""Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur",
      "ecole_elementaire"=>1,
      "position""=>"[
         44.08959199032698,
         6.853710118930262
      ],
      "coordx_origine"=>1008483.1,
      "precision_localisation""=>""Numéro de rue",
      "libelle_zone_animation_pedagogique""=>""NICE TROIS VALLEES",
      "longitude"=>6.853710118930262,
      "etat""=>""OUVERT",
      "code_departement""=>""006",
      "ecole_maternelle"=>1,
      "adresse_3""=>""06470 GUILLAUMES",
      "restauration"=>0,
      "coordy_origine"=>6339816.8,
      "ministere_tutelle""=>""MINISTERE DE L'EDUCATION NATIONALE",
      "code_zone_animation_pedagogique""=>""23063",
      "code_type_contrat_prive""=>""99",
      "type_contrat_prive""=>""SANS OBJET",
      "libelle_departement""=>""Alpes-Maritimes",
      "latitude"=>44.08959199032698,
      "pial""=>""0060066P",
      "siren_siret""=>""21060071400021",
      "code_postal""=>""06470",
      "nom_commune""=>""Guillaumes",
      "libelle_academie""=>""Nice",
      "libelle_nature""=>""ECOLE DE NIVEAU ELEMENTAIRE",
      "code_region""=>""93",
      "mail""=>""ce.0060285C@ac-nice.fr"
   },
   "geometry""=>"{
      "type""=>""Point",
      "coordinates""=>"[
         6.853710118930262,
         44.08959199032698
      ]
   },
   "record_timestamp""=>""2022-05-30T02:00:00Z"
}
```

Most of the fields you want to assign in `create_school` are nested under `school["fields"]`. If you want to for example get the value of `nom_etablissement` you can get the value using respective hash keys:

- `api_schools.rb:32`

```rb
name = school["fields"]["nom_etablissement"]
puts name

#> "Ecole"
```

[Here](https://learn.co/lessons/nested-hashes-intro) is a nice article that explains in a little more detail how nested hashes can be instantiated and accessed.

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to change key names to match your database table `schools` and then bulk the whole json into the database with [insert_all](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/insert_all).